# primefaces extensions codeMirror tag not being expanded

Tags: jsf, primefaces, codemirror, primefaces-extensions

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5 and trying to use the pe:codeMirror tag from primefaces extensions.

I added primefaces-extensions-3.2.0.jar and resources-codemirror-3.2.0.jar.
(also tried with 4.0.0 for these two jars - same behavior).

I added

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

My xhtml has:

```
<pe:codeMirror mode="javascript" value="#{grouperBean.selectedSearchName}" lineNumbers="true" theme="eclipse"/>
```

The bean is a session bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "grouperBean")
@SessionScoped
```

But on the page it seems to not expand - it stays a pe tag and therefore the browser shows nothing. I.e. when I look at the html page I see:

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row"><td role="gridcell" colspan="2">
    <pe:codeMirror mode="javascript" value="" lineNumbers="true" theme="eclipse">
    </pe:codeMirror>
</td></tr>
```

What am I missing that makes it not expand?
Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Browser errors?

Comment: Update all dependencies? Primefaces 3.5 is very old.